# "ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication" when using XMLTABLE view

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

When running even a simplest query that involves a view with XMLTABLE, Oracle (11g) returns `ORA-03113` error and terminates the connection. The query does not need to be large for this to happen, but it seems to always happen when a view with XMLTABLE parse is involved.

For example, assume a view with the following SQL:

```
CREATE VIEW test_view
AS SELECT id, date, xt.a
FROM test_xml_table x,
     XMLTABLE(XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'some:default:formation'),
              '//root/' PASSING XMLTYPE(x.xml) COLUMNS a
               VARCHAR2(256) PATH '//@a1') xt
WHERE xml IS NOT NULL;

WITH 
v_raw AS
 (SELECT * 
  FROM test_view WHERE id = 1),
v_aggregate AS
   (SELECT * 
    FROM v_raw)
SELECT 1 FROM v_raw WHERE rownum <= 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 FROM v_aggregate WHERE rownum <= 1;
```

I've simplified the query as much as possible for example purposes, but this is enough to result in the following error:

```
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
```

Both the `test_view` and simpler queries work fine and fast, it seems that this only happens when at least two views are simultaneously addressed in the select, one of which calls the view with the XML parser.

Any ideas what might be the problem or any possible workarounds without requiring a full rewrite? One solution I've found so far is to create a table instead of a view, but this is not the optimal solution.

Comment: This is usually a sign that the server process crashed. If you look at the alert log and/or trace files on the DB server it should give you more information about what is going wrong. This may be a known bug, but seeing what the server reported, and exactly which version and patch level of Oracle you are on, might narrow it down.

Comment: Also if you have access to Oracle support, look at master not 1506805.1 "Troubleshooting ORA-03113". If the information from the alert log doesn't help you identify an known issue on MoS you may need to raise a service request. Sounds like it *might* be bug 14671862 though...